# Tensorflow installation using SSE instructions with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, virtualenv, sse

I successfully installed cpu only tensorflow on ubuntu 16.04 using the default instructions provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_virtualenv). The instructions recommended using virtualenv and pip so I did not build from source. I had no problems installing with these instructions.

I validated my installation using the instructions provided [further down](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#validate_your_installation) on the same page, and while the program ran successfully, it output the following warnings.

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Hello, TensorFlow!
```

all the stackoverflow pages i've looked at only address people who have built from source using bazel, but don't seem to apply to people who used pip.

How do I recompile or update my installation so as to the SSE instructions?

Comment: it could be that you have some mixed environments issue, in the past i did use source code to install tensorflow on ubuntu 16.04, but since v.0.11 simple pip install works ok

Comment: I have compiled tensorflow to use SSE instructions. You can download the precompiled binaries from https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build.

Answer (score 3):

You must use `bazel` with `--config=opt` option to build a wheel customized for your architecture, and then use `pip` to install the resulting wheel.

I plan to occasionally upload 2014 MacBook + Xeon V3 optimized builds to  https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels

Once you install Bazel, making a wheel for your `pip` command is roughly as follows

```
./configure

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export flags="--config=opt --config=cuda -k"

bazel build $flags -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

Then wheel is dropped into `/tmp/tensorflow_pkg`

Comment: Hm, would you mind telling me at which step in the installation I should do this? I've literally just followed the instructions for virtualenv on the tensorflow tutorial, and don't know where I should do this configuration step

Comment: You need to follow instructions for building from source

Comment: I'm not really willing to deal with any problems that might come by building from source.. I'll just put it in as an issue on the tensorflow github for now and deal with warnings

edit: Pressed enter expecting new paragraph

Answer (score 1):

```
bazel build --linkopt='-lrt' -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse3-k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

If above solved your problem ,vote up `Christian Frei's` answer on [How do I resolve these tensorflow warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270739/how-do-i-resolve-these-tensorflow-warnings/42975902#42975902)

Answer (score 0):

Those are just warnings. As per this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7778), add this lines before importing TensorFlow,

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
```

I also have the same problem, but the suggested link solved my problem.

Also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135194/5255006), it will help to know more about SSE information and also the different types of log indicators.